# Isomorphic `fmap` in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

Does such a thing exist in Haskell's Prelude?

```
wfmap :: Functor f
      => a
      -> (a -> b)
      -> (b -> a)
      -> (b -> f b)
      -> f a
wfmap x u w g = fmap (w) (g (u x))
```

In a project I'm working on, I often found myself 'converting' a type to another, process it and 'converting' it back.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to take `x :: a` as the last argument?

Comment: @leftaroundabout oh yeah, it does. Thanks for pointing that out. But this is just pseudocode to explain my issue. Its just that I have a lot of functions and types that use a pattern similar to this and I'm wondering if theres a better way to go about doing this.

Comment: Your `wfmap` declares 5 arguments in the type, but only 4 in the definition. I think you just have an extra argument of type `a` in the type.

Comment: `Functor f => (b -> f b) -> a -> f a` is also called `Lens' a b` and is the centerpiece of the [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library. Your example could end up looking like `wfmap x u w g = (iso u w %%~ g) x`, though of course you wouldn't give wfmap its own name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reordering the arguments, as leftaroundabout suggests, allows for a tidier definition:

```
wfmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> (b -> f b) -> a -> f a
wfmap u w g = fmap w . g . u
```

As for library support, *lens* provides [nifty support for isomorphisms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html). A bit more broadly, as Gurkenglas notes...

> `Functor f => (b -> f b) -> a -> f a` is also called `Lens' a b` and is the centerpiece of the lens library.

Without diving into the details of how and why that works, one consequence is that your function might be defined as:

```
wfmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> (b -> f b) -> a -> f a
wfmap u w g = (iso u w) g
```

Or even:

```
wfmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (b -> a) -> (b -> f b) -> a -> f a
wfmap = iso
```

`wfmap` is just (a specialised version of) `iso`, which gives out a function which can be used to convert an `b -> f b` function on the isomorphism "destination" to an `a -> f a` one on the isomorphism "source".

It is also worth mentioning [`mapping`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:mapping), which can be used for the somewhat different purpose of applying `fmap` on the other side of an isomorphism:

```
GHCi> :t \u w g -> over (mapping (iso u w)) (fmap g)
\u w g -> over (mapping (iso u w)) (fmap g)
  :: Functor f => (s -> a) -> (b -> t) -> (a -> b) -> f s -> f t
GHCi> :t \u w g -> under (mapping (iso u w)) (fmap g)
\u w g -> under (mapping (iso u w)) (fmap g)
  :: Functor f => (s -> a) -> (b -> a1) -> (a1 -> s) -> f b -> f a
```

Finally, note that `iso u w` can be replaced by any `Iso` you might find in the libraries or have predefined elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for this! :)